# Emacs: How do I create a new "empty" buffer whenever creating a new frame?

Tags: emacs

My Emacs is on OS X system. Is there any way to make a new frame defaulted to an empty buffer whenever I use <kbd>⌘N</kbd> (just like the way TextEdit works)? I prefer to write contents first and decide an appropriate filename later. However, Emacs wants me to decide the filename first and write contents later. I don't see any advantage for it. Does anyone know why Emacs works that way?

Basically, if I use <kbd>C-x 5 2</kbd>, Emacs always pops up a frame with whatever file I am currently working on. This is inconvenient. I also don't want my Emacs to pop up a new frame defaulted to `*scratch*` (many Google search results somehow suggest this approach). I prefer it to have a buffer temporarily called "Untitled" in the new frame, and if I use <kbd>⌘N</kbd> again, Emacs pops up another temporarily "Untitled 2" buffer, and so on. In this way, I can decide the buffer filenames later.

Comment: So, just replace `*scratch*` with `*Untitled` in the solutions you found.

Comment: I want to have multiple new "Untitled" buffers. So far, all new frames point to the same "Untitled" buffer.

Comment: Shouldn't the buffers have unique names?  `*untitled-01*` `*untitled-02*` `*untitled-03*`  If the names are not unique, I'm afraid you will be essentially looking at the same buffer in every frame displaying that buffer name.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can create new buffers with `switch-to-buffer`.  Type `C-x b`, enter a buffer name, and press `RET`.  If no buffer with that name exists, Emacs creates a new one automatically in Fundamental Mode.  You may switch to any other mode as usual with `M-x`, e.g. `M-x python-mode`.  To change the default buffer, set the default value of `major-mode` to the desired buffer.

If you'd like to have a buffer name chosen automatically, and create a new frame, however, you need to write your own command:

```lisp
(defun lunaryorn-new-buffer-frame ()
  "Create a new frame with a new empty buffer."
  (interactive)
  (let ((buffer (generate-new-buffer "untitled")))
    (set-buffer-major-mode buffer)
    (display-buffer buffer '(display-buffer-pop-up-frame . nil))))
```

Bind this to `C-c n`:

```lisp
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c n") #'lunaryorn-new-buffer-frame)
```

Now pressing `C-c n` creates a new frame with a new empty buffer named “untitled” where x is a consecutive number.

Comment: Nice - I didn't know about generate-new-buffer, so I tried to implement it from scratch.

Comment: @lunaryorn, I just tried your function, it works! Is there any reason you bind it to (kbd "C-c n") instead of (kbd "s-n")? I prefer to use the system default CMD-n, it is more intuitive to me. Did you bind it that way because of several potential keybinding conflicts in the MELPA/ELPA packages?

Comment: @BartSimpson `C-c n` is “safe”, in that it won't conflict with bindings from Emacs itself, or other modes, because `C-c <letter>` are reserved for users, according to the [Key Binding Conventions](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Key-Binding-Conventions.html).  Neither Emacs nor any other well-behaved mode will ever bind these, so there's no risk of a conflict.  Of course you may use whatever other binding you prefer, as long as you aware that it might conflict with Emacs or other modes.

Comment: @lunaryorn, thank you! I will keep that in mind for my keybindings!

Comment: What if I wanted to open the buffer in the same window instead of in a new one? Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

The following will create a buffer with a unique name. The buffer is not associated with any file, so if/when you ever `C-x C-s` `save-buffer`, you will be prompted to supply a filename.

```
(defun empty-frame ()
  "Open a new frame with a buffer named Untitled<N>.

The buffer is not associated with a file."
  (interactive)
  (switch-to-buffer-other-frame (generate-new-buffer "Untitled")))
```

Comment: As soon as I clicked Post Answer, I saw that @lunaryorn had posted something similar, and with the added twist of setting a major mode. Oh well.

Answer (score 6):

This might work for you, if I understand your request:

```el
(defun empty-frame ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((fl (make-temp-file "Untitled")))
    (switch-to-buffer-other-frame fl)))
```

This will open a new temporary file for each new buffer. If you'd rather not actually create the file, you can use this instead:

```el
(defun empty-frame ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((bn "Untitled-")
        (num 1))
    (while
        (get-buffer (concat bn (number-to-string num))) 
      (setq num (1+ num))) 
    (switch-to-buffer-other-frame
     (concat bn (number-to-string num)))))
```

Comment: Don't map and search over the entire buffer list on each iteration.  Test for the existence of a buffer with the specific name instead, with `get-buffer`.  But really, use `generate-new-buffer`.

Comment: That's better, thanks. I'll leave this here as an (inferior) alternative to your answer.

Answer (score 4):

You've seen answers as to how to create new "Untitled" buffers, but as for why Emacs wants you to first choose a name, some of the reasons are:

- Historical: that's just how it worked, and once you get used to it, it's no worse than the alternative.
- Major modes and various other details are usually chosen based on the name of the file.  So instead of creating an Untitled buffer and having to choose whether to put it into LaTeX mode or C mode, you just open a file with extension ".tex" or ".c".
- Having a file name means that Emacs can use the standard auto-save procedure, whereas with the Untitled approach, applications need to have some special way to auto-save those Untitled documents at some "standard" place.

Answer (score 3):

C-x b *untitled* will open new buffer if not exist. Also, see [Emacs manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Select-Buffer.html#Select-Buffer)